# MacOS Storyboard: Prevent Container View from clipping its contents

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard

I have an NSBox in a View Controller embedded within a Container View, holding the *piston rail* (see below image).

[image]

The problem is, the view controller in the Container View gets clipped to the same fragment, irrespective of the width parameters of the piston rail views.

So my question is, how can I maintain the respective ratios of the buttons so that no matter in what size Container View they are placed they will not be clipped and fully display?

Below is an example of the scale of the clipping:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Layout is 'Automatic' instead of 'Translates Mask into Constraints'. Autoresizing square right below can help as well. And in general remove constraints if you do not know what they do.